# How to insert line break into Rich Text field from Field Update

Tags: workflow, formula-field

I've a workflow field update that's updating a rich text field type. I've tried using BR() to insert line breaks but I don't see that line break when viewing the standard detail page for the record.

My field update formula currently is:

```
'Dear, ' + Assigned_To__r.Full_Name__c + 
BR() + 
'Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet' + 
'\r\n' + 
'Thanks, ' + Owner:User.Full_Name__c
```

The BR() does nothing and the \r\n is left as literal.

What might I be missing? What can I try?

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard html tags like `<br>` tags.

e.g.

```
'Dear, ' + Assigned_To__r.Full_Name__c + 
'<br/>' + 
'Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet' + 
'\r\n' + 
'Thanks, ' + Owner:User.Full_Name__c
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. Makes me wonder what the BR() is for then?

Comment: The br() function is used in standard formula fields.. (I think that they disallowed pure html in formula half a year ago.)

Answer (score 0):

```
"Dear, " & Assigned_To__r.Full_Name__c & 
BR() & 
"Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet" &
BR() & 
"Thanks, " & Owner:User.Full_Name__c
```

Answer (score 0):

P tag gives new Line in Rich Text Area Field. Please refer the below.

```
<p>Header</p><p>Content</p>
```

I got the following result:

```
Header
Content
```

Comment: This format will not work in a workflow field update, which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: it will work in richtext field with process builder/flow.
for workflow rules, u can use "BR()" tag